# I have made date as index of a dataframe in pandas. How can I search rows for a particular date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame named inject. I have made a column name date as the index of the data frame inject. I want to find the rows corresponding to a particular date. The data type of column date is datetime.

```
      inject_2017["2017-04-20"]
```

Writing this code throwing me an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `inject_2017.loc["2017-04-20"]`

This way you can select the row (or group of rows) with the corresponding datetime index.